# Cannot access the Internet even though it shows to be connected on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wired-networking

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, have a wired connection and `ifconfig` shows an IP address is assigned, yet I cannot access the Internet:

```
chetan@chetan-Aspire-E5-511:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:a9:63:e2:7e:37  
          inet addr:192.168.0.114  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fec0::a:faa9:63ff:fee2:7e37/64 Scope:Site
          inet6 addr: 2002:b69e:138d:a:55b:4b1a:d048:b11a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2002:b69e:138d:a:faa9:63ff:fee2:7e37/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::faa9:63ff:fee2:7e37/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fec0::a:55b:4b1a:d048:b11a/64 Scope:Site
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30795 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2645473 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:30866 (30.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2021 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2021 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:140673 (140.6 KB)  TX bytes:140673 (140.6 KB)
```

I have seen similar sorts of question answered here, but the solutions are not working in my case or I don’t get it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information?
The contents of your

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

Like Giacomo1968 said, what happens when you ping `8.8.8.8`?

If that is not possible, can you ping your gateway?

Also start with basics. Check the cabling.